# Prevent Resizing GridviewColumn in Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have Devexpress GridView and I do not want to allow user to resize the columns of it.
I have written following clientside event:

```
grdTicketDetails.ClientSideEvents.ColumnResizing= "function(s,e){ e.processOnServer = false;}";
```

But it doesn't work. 
How can I prevent user to resize the gridview columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does actually does is callback to the ColumnResizing event on the server.

You should set

> AspxGridView.SettingsBehavior.ColumnResizeMode

back to its default of "Disabled" to prevent the end user from resizing columns.

Answer (score 1):

By default, this option is disabled:

[ColumnResizeMode Enumeration](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewColumnResizeModeEnumtopic)

[Grid Columns - Resizing Columns](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Columns/ColumnResizing.aspx)

If (for some reasons) it was enabled, revert it back to a default mode by setting the [ASPxGridView.SettingsBehavior.ColumnResizeMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewBehaviorSettings_ColumnResizeModetopic) property to "**ColumnResizeMode.Disabled**"